# How to call Java (JDK 11) jar in .net program (C#)

Tags: java, .net, jar, ikvm

Currently working on Java Project and want to call and use my jar file in .net(C#) Visual Studio,
Was Currently using IKVM.WINDWARD(8.5.3),IKVM 8 and working fine with JDK 8 but i require a solution for JDK 11, There might be a scenario that IKVM is not getting Future updates, so is there any better way to do the same, explored about the JNI but as it uses C/C++ it is not needed in the current project, please suggest a solution to perform this operation.

sample reference program used from
https://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/wiki/Run_a_jar_file_on_the_fly/

wanting a better solution or a new way to call java(11) jar in .net(C#) code.

Comment: What is the current way you are doing the call? You should provide a minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. What are the issues with JDK 11? How do you define better solution for the context of this question?

Comment: getting java.lang.unsupportedClassVersion(55.0) 
as it doesnt support it

Comment: That error means that you are trying to execute code compiled for Java 11 with an older version of Java. It doesn't answer any of my questions.